# What is the relationship between the two forms of Statement.getMoreResults()?

Tags: jdbc

The method `Statement.getMoreResults()` exists in two variants: one which does not take an argument, and another which takes an integer argument. The second variant accepts one of three constants `CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT`, `KEEP_CURRENT_RESULT`, and `CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS`. My question is, is the first variant equivalent to some constant passed to the second variant (and if so which one?) Is `getMoreResults()` equivalent to `getMoreResults(CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT)` or `getMoreResults(CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)` or neither?

Comment: [right from the javadocs for getMoreResults()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--): "*Moves to this Statement object's next result, returns true if it is a ResultSet object, **and implicitly closes any current ResultSet** object(s) obtained with the method getResultSet*".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, are you saying that `getMoreResults()` is equivalent to `getMoreResults(CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT)` or to `getMoreResults(CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)`? I can't work out from your comment which answer you are supporting.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC is a collection of interfaces and required behaviors. Whether or not `getMoreResults()` call `getMoreResults(int)` is up to the individual JDBC implementation.

However, the API doc of [`getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--) says:

> Moves to this `Statement` object's next result, returns `true` if it is a `ResultSet` object, and implicitly closes **any current `ResultSet` object(s)** obtained with the method `getResultSet`.

This is the equivalent of calling `getMoreResults(Statement.CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)`.

[`Statement.CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS) is defined as:

> The constant indicating that **all `ResultSet` objects that have previously been kept open** should be closed when calling `getMoreResults`.

The use of any and all might cause some confusion, but they both indicate that any previously opened `ResultSet` should be closed.

Interestingly enough (as you pointed out in the comments), `getMoreResults(Statement.CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)` should throw an `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` if the driver does not support multiple open results.

The behavior for `getMoreResults()` described in the apidoc and in the JDBC specification however do indicate that it should be equivalent.

The JDBC 4.2 specification says in 13.1.2.3:

> By default, each call to the method `getMoreResult`s closes any previous
>   `ResultSet` object returned by the method `getResultSet`.

Based on this, in a driver that does not support multiple open results, `getMoreResults()` is equivalent to `getMoreResults(Statement.CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT)`, and in a driver that does support multiple open results, it is equivalent to `getMoreResults(Statement.CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)`. I think this distinction is a bit weird and unnecessary, because in a driver that does not support multiple open results, closing the current result is the same as closing all results (as there is only one result). I will take this up with the JDBC Expert Group.

Comment: Counter-argument: per the JavaDoc, if `DatabaseMetaData.supportsMultipleOpenResults()` is false, `getMoreResults(CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)` is supposed to throw `SQLFeatureException`, but `getMoreResults()` is not supposed to throw `SQLFeatureException`. In my mind, this implies that `getMoreResults()` and `getMoreResults(CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS)` are non-equivalent, and that `getMoreResults()` is actually equivalent to `getMoreResults(CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT)`

Comment: @SimonKissane That is a very good point. Although then it is highly confusing that `getMoreResults()` talks about "`ResultSet` object*(s)*"

Comment: I think the JavaDocs here are very confusingly worded, and whichever interpretation one adopts there are going to be reasonable arguments for the other interpretation.

Comment: @SimonKissane I will take this up with the JDBC expert group, maybe they can clarify this for JDBC 4.3